# Members in treatment group serve as controls for other treatment members to eliminate unmeasured confounders in pre/post observational study?

Tags: difference-in-difference, matching, confounding, case-control-study

Consider a typical observational healthcare study where pre/post health outcomes among patients receiving a treatment or care program are compared to a counterfactual control group who didn't receive the treatment. The goal is to estimate the average treatment effect (ATE).

Even after matching/conditioning on demographic, healthcare utilization, and medical diagnosis variables there may be selection bias in our treatment and control groups due to unmeasured confounders such as health lifestyles, aversion to receiving healthcare, etc.

**Can we control for unmeasured confounders by matching members in the treatment group to *other treatment members* who are similar but received the treatment later in the study?** We'd create a "pseudo-exposure" date for the control group members so that pre/post trends in the outcome may be compared over the same time period.

For example, match Member 1 to Member 2 to compare pre-period = 2019 to post-period = 2020, and match Member 3 to Member 4 to compare pre-period = July - June 2020/21 to post-period = July - June 2021/22.

Drawbacks: Treatment-treatment matching entails looking at a different population and therefore estimating the Average Treatment Effect on the Treated (ATT) rather than ATE. And if the pre/post periods are aligned for most patients, the pool of treatment group controls will be small.

[image]

[image]